# palette not shown in texture paint mode

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

The palette is not shown at any brush i choose

Also i am not able to paint from any texture, and if i try for example using clone brush i would get just a black brush

If i try on another project these things it works, so, do you have any idea what may be wrong set up?

Any help is appreciated :)

Edit:
I realised that the problem is that some brushes miss, and i am still working so solve this
Some says that it s enough to open your project unchecking the load ui option, but for me it didn't work

[image: no palette and texture painting not working]

Answer (score 1):

You are using a mask brush which doesn't use colour.

Choosing a colour from the palette only makes sense with brushes that apply colour to an image such as draw. Brushes like smudge, mask and blur don't use colour information so don't see the palette. While the clone brush applies colour it takes the colour from the starting position not the current brush colour, so also doesn't get the palette visible.